# Intellisense while writing XAML

Tags: visual-studio-2008, xaml, blend

Using VS 2008, or Blend 3, is there any way I can get intellisense for the available properties when creating styles in XAML? I thought I heard there was a third-party freebie that did this.

In the snippet below, I want intellisense for the properties like FontSize, Margin, Width, etc.

```
<Style x:Key="MyTextBoxStyle" TargetType="TextBox">
   <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12"/>
   <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"/>
   <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
   <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
   <Setter Property="Width" Value="200"/>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick Bing came up with the following link. Don't know if it's applicable in your case, but it sure was in mine. [The problem shows up if you install the Windows SDK after VS2008](http://wildermuth.com/2008/02/04/Getting_Silverlight_XAML_Intellisense_in_VS2008.aspx)

And Shawn Wildermuth had a good tip for editing Silverlight XAML... [use the XML editor instead of what Visual Studio wants to use for all XAML (The WPF Designer)](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/windowssdk/thread/dd6f14ed-e582-4b49-9358-64f2afaec151/)